# Creating excel and csv files in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am currently creating excel files with a few thousand rows of data in my vb.net application but I am wondering if it would be faster to create a csv file instead?

Comment: Try it and find out?  I would expect creating the CSV file to be faster given that it's simple text.

Comment: I was asking just so I didn't waste time changing it all then maybe having to change it all back. I am sure someone must have already tried, hence the question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just an example, you can try like this way. Please implement the code as per your requirement.

```
Dim csvFilePath As String = "C:\Test.csv" 'Path to create or existing file
        Dim outFile As IO.StreamWriter = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(csvFilePath, False)
        outFile.WriteLine("Field1, Field2")
        outFile.WriteLine("1, 2")
        outFile.WriteLine("3, 3")
        outFile.Close()
        Console.WriteLine(My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(csvFilePath))
```

[Demo - Datatable to CSV](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/665519/Writing-a-DataTable-to-a-CSV-File)